# TestNG: All subsequent Test classes are skipped when @BeforeClass method fails?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, annotations, testng

#### My setup:

- A **TestBase class** containing a @BeforeClass method
- **Several Test classes** extending from TestBase class and also containing a @BeforeClass method
- testNG 6.8.8

#### Why this setup?:

- I need the @BeforeClass in the TestBase class to provide setup that all testclasses will need and I don't want to repeat in every Test class. For example thread-id-dependent login credentials.
- TestBase class also instantiates the Selenium WebDriver
- I need the @BeforeClass in the Test classes to initialize everything that all @Test methods will need to use but that only needs to (or must) be built/invoked once for all tests. This includes calls to said WebDriver instance (that's why a "normal" constructor doesn't work here)

#### Here's what happens:

When I run the tests via a testNG xml file and there is an **exception within the @BeforeClass** method of one of the Test classes, then **all subsequent Test classes are skipped by TestNG**.

### Why does this happen? How to prevent it?

When I change the annotation in the TestBase class to **@BeforeSuite** for example, then **all tests are run**, even if there is an exception in on of the @BeforeClass methods.

#### Example:

When you run the xml file, complete RunAllTestClasses02 class is skipped.

**testNG xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name = "MiscSuite">
    <test name = "MiscTest">
        <classes >
            <class name="drkthng.misc.RunAllTestClasses01" />
            <class name="drkthng.misc.RunAllTestClasses02" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**TestBase class with a @BeforeClass method:**

```
public abstract class RunAllTestClassesBase {

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        // do something that all Test classes will need
    }
}
```

**Test class that throws Exception within @BeforeClass method:**

```
public class RunAllTestClasses01 extends RunAllTestClassesBase {

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void Test01() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132734/beforeclass-and-inheritance-order-of-execution) answer could help

Comment: @ErkiM. thanks man! this definitely sheds some light. Still there's the question why all subsequent Test are skipped, just because one! class fails.

Comment: I believe it's by design as your tests depend on the outcome of `@BeforeClass` and it fails, hence the execution is stopped. To over come this, you could annotate your tests with `alwaysRun`, that by the [docs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) : `alwaysRun  If set to true, this test method will always be run even if it depends on a method that failed.` I have not tested this myself, let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: Bug in testng I suppose - fixed in 6.9.5 it seems : https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/471

Comment: @niharika_neo thank you so much!!! this solved the whole issue!! won't you put this as an answer? because that's what it is regarding my updated question (testng version number 6.8.8) - otherwise I'll have to do this myself und you won't get the whole credit ;-)

Comment: :) done! Now give me my points! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in Testng. solved in 6.9.5.  Please upgrade.

Comment: unfortunately the bug is not completely resolved -> Problem with children being skipped when one child fails during its own \@beforeClass method still holds, if children have \@beforeClass and the parent class has \@beforeClass AND \@afterClass.

Comment: Same here - upgrading didn't solve it for me. Switching to `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite` did.

Comment: still see the bug even on 6.11

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@AfterClass(alwaysrun = true)` or/and `@AfterMethod(alwaysrun=true)` as by default they are skipped if either BeforeClass or BeforeMethod are not completed.

The documentation on testNG Configuration Failures, Policy, and alwaysRun explains whether/when configuration failures cause listener methods (`alwaysRun` and other listeners) to be skipped, failure policies and best practices.