# Multiple BeforeClass annotations in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

In my code , I Have a `BaseTest.java` class which is extended by multiple classes . I declared a `@BeforeTest` before class method to be run before every class . Now if I also declare some class specific before class in respective classes . What is priority of execution of the before classes . Does the before class method in base class is taken into account . In my piece of code the one in base class not even seem to be invoked . What am I doing wrong .

Comment: can you show your code what you did yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@BeforeClass and inheritance - order of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132734/beforeclass-and-inheritance-order-of-execution)

Answer (score 0):

If there is class A and you have a BeforeClass method and if class B extends A with the Beforeclass method too. The execution of class A Beforeclass occurs first and the latter.